# How to update Centos 7 only for security enhance and minimize code modification?

Tags: centos, centos7

Based on [this post](https://www.centos.org/forums/viewtopic.php?f=51&t=66317#p278743),

> For CentOS you must either apply all updates or none, there is no way to select only security updates.

Then, the only way is `yum update` if I want to reduce safety issues.

How to know whether my PHP,javascript code should be revised after centos 7 system update?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> How to know whether my PHP,javascript code should be revised after CentOS 7 system update?

You either know your custom applications very well and can determine beforehand from release notes and errata descriptions that your application(s) will be impacted, or like most people you are not that intimately familiar with the code and then you perform upgrade(s) first on a non-production system and test and validate if applications still work as before.

In general though: Red Hat aims to keep the software shipped within a main release such as RHEL/CentOS 7 stable and fully compatible for the life cycle of the release. Official security and errata updates should be backwards compatible and not break third-party and custom applications linked to and build upon those packages. https://access.redhat.com/articles/rhel-abi-compatibility

Comment: How to get `release notes and errata descriptions` before centos 7 `yum update`?

Comment: Red Hat publishes them publicly on https://access.redhat.com/errata/#/ or specific for [Red Hat Enterpise Linux](https://access.redhat.com/errata/#/?q=&p=1&sort=portal_publication_date%20desc&rows=10&portal_product=Red%20Hat%20Enterprise%20Linux) - Typically you can expect that a `yum update` will install everything  since the date of the previous time your system was updated

Answer (score -2):

You may also use `yum update --security` to apply security patches only. This will apply the patches released on the latest erratas.

Comment: CentOS does not tag updates as security updates, so this does not work. It is only applicable to RHEL.